# why this WaitLock gets stuck?

Tags: c#, .net

I read a book which shows a simple `SimpleWaitLock`, which is a kernel-mode construct that uses `AutoResetEvent`. So I tried some experiments as below:

```
class Program {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      using (SimpleWaitLock swl = new SimpleWaitLock()) {
         Task.Run(() => {
            swl.Enter();
            Console.WriteLine("First");
            swl.Leave();
         });
         Task.Run(() => {
            swl.Enter();
            Console.WriteLine("Second");
            swl.Leave();
         });
         Task.Run(() => {
            swl.Enter();
            Console.WriteLine("Third");
            swl.Leave();
         });
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}

class SimpleWaitLock : IDisposable {
   private readonly AutoResetEvent m_available;

   public SimpleWaitLock() {
      m_available = new AutoResetEvent(true);   // Initially free
   }

   public void Enter() {
      // Block in kernel until resource available
      m_available.WaitOne();
   }

   public void Leave() {
      // Let another thread access the resource
      m_available.Set();
   }

   public void Dispose() {
      m_available.Dispose();
   }
}
```

I know the purpose of the lock is to lock/release shared resource, but I just print sth to the console for simple.

When I run the program, nothing print out to the console, I'm confused.

Comment: The Task class is dangerous when you use it to write fire-and-forget code.  You can't see any exception until you wait or obtain the result of the task.  Append `.Wait()` to the Run() calls to get ahead.  Also fixes the other bug in this code, it can't sequence the tasks correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A task passed to `Task.Run` can start at any time. In particular, it can start after control flow on the main thread leaves the `using` block. This means that when a task begins execution, *the SimpleWaitLock (and its AutoResetEvent) could be in a disposed state!*

One solution is to make your Main method async, and await on the tasks inside the using block with [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0). (Note that async Main methods require your C# version to be at least 7.1.)

Alternatively, you can use [`Task.WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-5.0), which doesn't require your Main method to be async but will block the main thread until all tasks have completed.